# Is there a base map package in R to show buildings?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, ggmap

I have lat/long data with household income and I would like to overlay the points with the household income over a base map of buildings like something you would see in Google maps (just the outline of the buildings, not a satellite image). I tried looking into R mapview and osmdata packages but I can't find how to make a base map/ a base map for buildings. Any leads would be helpful! Thanks!

```
#create data
lat <- c(33.97463, 33.97458, 33.97460, 33.97520, 33.97403, 33.97607) 
long <- c(-117.9180, -117.9183 , -117.9185, -117.9186 , -117.9184, -117.9184)
income <- c(15000, 30000, 50000, 20000, 30000, 100000)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(lat, long, income))

#plot household income as lat/long points 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = data, aes(x = long, y = lat, 
                                         colour = income),size =2)+
  scale_color_stepsn(n.breaks = 5, colours = terrain.colors(5))+
  theme_bw()

#add basemap of buildings like Google Maps
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your sample data has very small area but I think this will help you. By `ggmap::qmplot`,

```
ggmap::qmplot(long, lat, data = data, colour = I('red'), zoom = 16)
```

You might have to change zoom for another data yourself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! It is a subset of a larger dataset so that is why it is such a small area. I applied your code but it is not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for buildings for each dot but when I plot it I just get streets. I tried changing the zoom to see if it would give more detail but it did not

Comment: @KCRay For example data for `qmplot`, it does show buildings and city. [For crime data](https://bbolker.github.io/stat744/spatial/4crime.html). I'm curious that your data doesn't show buildings near crimson crest Dr